# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.(2722)

Tags: typescript

**Edit: Solution is not the accepted answer. For the solution [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76699507/9041632).**

Here is some working code & usage. ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJpK5N))

```js
type A = { [key: string]: () => 123 }

function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (key: keyof T) => arg[key](); // no error because 'noUncheckedIndexedAccess' not enabled
}

console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })('hello'));
// [123, 123]
```

But the same code causes an error with `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled. ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WK3JyW))

```js
type A = { [key: string]: () => 123 }

function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (key: keyof T) => arg[key](); // error because 'noUncheckedIndexedAccess' enabled
}

console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })('hello'));
// [123, 123]
```

What I don't understand is, why the error

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.(2722)
```

even appears. `key` is IMO clearly a key of arg and thus `arg[key]` certainly not `undefined`.

Can someone explain this to me and how to fix this? (turning off `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is not an option)

I played around adding other options such as `noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is enabled the compiler strictly checks the indexed access. You can declare an object with the type `Record<string, string>`, but it is not realistic to how every string in that object as a key. So to ensure type-safety when the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is enabled it makes the result of an index access optional (undefined). To fix it you can use optional chaining to invoke the function:

```
function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (key: keyof T) => arg[key]?.(); 
}
```

Note that `arg[key] && arg[key]()` won't work, again because of the type-safety

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDaBrCIBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gLq4AUAlAgHxQCMATAMxQC+AULwDMArqQDGwYgHtSUYaQ4AeACpQIAD2ARSAEzyxGNAIaFyuJQyS8o1qIQjAhhGTUw4oryQKjmmUY+QwsSgB+ADp6AG4oXj5eUWk8SQAbCFCkyXIaOQ4aFAALCCT02gZ4ZnYOABooPOSUkt8KnjoaAHICoslWujoI3gB6frQK6orKIA)

Comment: I don't understand "but it is not realistic to how every string in that object as a key". How exactly do I perform "unchecked index access" in my example when `arg[key]` is definitely `() => 123` and *never* undefined and key is, by definition, a key of arg?

Comment: `string` is any possible string. Can you imagine an object containing an infinite number of keys? Even if your object is `Record<string, something>` doesn't mean that it has every string in it. Your error is not about the key is not suitable to access the object, but for the `arg[key]` being possibly undefined.

Comment: I [derived a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76699507/9041632) based on your `string` problematic explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (and how I derived it) from the accepted answer. This solves the initial problem.

**Step 1:** Transform problem to ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLXjAm))

```js
type A = { [key in 'hello' | 'holle']: () => 123 }

function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (key: keyof T) => arg[key]();
}

console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })('hello')); // no error = good

// console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })('hellox')); // error = good
```

**Step 2:** ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1kXGm))

```js
type A<T> = { [key in keyof T]: () => 123 }

function fun3<T extends A<T>>(arg: T) {
    return (key: keyof T) => arg[key]();
}

console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })('hello')); // no error = good

// console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })('hellox')); // error = good
```